# User Images in certain places still pointing to old mysite

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service, migration, user-profile-property, mysite

We did a content DB backup restore from one server to another (both being SP 2013). We found that in certain places the user images still point to old mysite thumbnail image url. One of the location being the "Shared With" tab on list settings. What are we missing and how can we resolve it?

Comment: Are you saying that you also changed the URL of the My Site Host?